# Translation of python loop into R

Tags: python, r, loops

Can someone help me how to translate this python loop

```
for i, y in enumerate(data.beta[1:]):
  row = data[data['ids'] == y.split("'")[1]].iloc[0]
  X[i] = np.r_[1, row[['attribute1', 'attribute2']]]
```

into R?

I tried out something like this:

```
for (i in seq_along(nevo_results_with_d$beta_labels[-1])) {
   for (label in seq_along(nevo_results_with_d$beta_labels[-1])) {
    row = product_data[product_data['product_ids'] == strsplit(label,split="'",fixed=TRUE)[1]]
    X[i] = rbind(1, row[['sugar', 'mushy']])}
}
```

But it does not work out yet. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. showing your input data.frame (you can use `dput` for that) and the required output. Also the error or warning message would be helpful.

Comment: You’ve transformed a simple loop into a nested loop, that can’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ideas (and a bonus). In each case, I'm creating a vector of logicals based on your condition that is indexed by the rows of the input dataframe. Then we can use that vector to subset the data.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(product_ids = c("big", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium"),
           beta_labels = c("big'one", "giant'four", "medium'zero", "big'eight'seventy", "big'nine", "medium'three"))

df
#>   product_ids       beta_labels
#> 1         big           big'one
#> 2       small        giant'four
#> 3      medium       medium'zero
#> 4       small big'eight'seventy
#> 5       small          big'nine
#> 6      medium      medium'three
```

Looping over each row of a dataframe in a loop:

```
rows <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    temp <- df[i, "product_ids"] == strsplit(df[i, "beta_labels"], split = "'", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
    rows <- c(rows, temp)
}
rows
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
df[rows,]
#>   product_ids  beta_labels
#> 1         big      big'one
#> 3      medium  medium'zero
#> 6      medium medium'three
```

Vectorized with apply family:

```
rows2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  df[i, "product_ids"] == strsplit(df[i, "beta_labels"], split = "'", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
  })
rows2
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
df[rows2,]
#>   product_ids  beta_labels
#> 1         big      big'one
#> 3      medium  medium'zero
#> 6      medium medium'three
```

If you used a vectorized function to check your condition, subsetting is even simpler:

```
df[df$product_ids == gsub(pattern = "^([A-Za-z]*)'.*", replacement = "\\1", x = df$beta_labels),]
#>   product_ids  beta_labels
#> 1         big      big'one
#> 3      medium  medium'zero
#> 6      medium medium'three
```

Created on 2022-01-06 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)